# Git remote branch reuse huge files

Tags: git

Hi
I have 2 local branches - `master` and `test`.

I added a 20MB file to branch `master` and pushed it to the remote `master`.

Now I merge `master` into `test`. and pushed `test` to the remote `test`.

Now I have to upload the 20MB again. Anyway around this issue?

Both remote branches are on the same remote.

```
(master) touch hugefile
(master) git add hugefile 
(master) git commit -m "huge"
(master) git push origin master  (upload 20MB)
(test)   git merge master
(test)   git push origin test       (< upload 20 MB again)
```

**SOLUTION**

There may be a problem with `autocrlf=True` and **binary files** that are **detected as text**.

I worked arround this issue by forcing git to detect *.pdf files as  binary files.

http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2007/09/git-binary-files-and-cherry-picking.html

Comment: Are you sure it's really doing the upload all over again? I would think that git should be smart enough to transmit information about what changed, rather than resending the entire file.

Comment: strange circumstances, now everything works fine. Maybe a `git fetch --all` was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will not upload the file again. The file contents will be stored as blobs in the repository which multiple commits can point to (via. trees). When you do your new commits, the tree objects created for them will point to the file you added the first time. In your specific case, the merge will simply move the `test` branch to the same position as `head` and send that information back to the server when you push. There will be no addition of files at all.